# Problem with showing customer avator in account information page

Tags: magento-2.1, htaccess, file-permissions

I have added a custom image field to customer and I want to show it in customer information page. when it is uploaded it saves into pub/media/customer folder.
Now I want to have its url to see the image in browser, whereas I can see http://../pub/media/catalog/.../catalog1.jpg but when I enter url http://../pub/media/customer/.../avator.jpg in the browser it returns 403 forbidden error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You need to put `avator.jpg` into   `<magento-install-dir>/pub/media/catalog/product/customer` directory

Then call  `http://../pub/media/catalog/product/customer/avator.jpg`

its should work, let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: when user uploads an image the jpg file saves in this path: magento-folder/pub/media/customer/5/4/avator.jpeg but when I call ir in browser: http://localhost/magento-folder/pub/media/customer/5/4/avator.jpeg it returns 403 error!

Comment: I have same issue before, i changed  this path `<magento-install-dir>/pub/media/catalog/product/customer`  to store customer image.  its works fine.

Comment: but I can not change upload path! I added a custom field to customer and it produces a folder for customer file upload.

Comment: try to change 777 permission to `pub/media/customer` to this folder.  chmod  -R 777 `<>m2-install/pub/media/customer`

Comment: The problem was a .htaccess file which created when uploading done and it was hidden and deny all accesses! I edited it and the problem solved! thank you all..